# Evaluating polynomials to 5 significant figures but only 1 sig fig returns - Maple Programming

Tags: polynomials, maple

For example, A polynomial is defined as follows:

f := (x, y) -> 333.75*y^6 + x^2*(11*x^2*y^2 - y^6 - 12*y^4 - 2) + 5.5*y^8 + 1/2*x/y

In maple, I look to evaluate this to 5 significant figures like so:

```
evalf[5](f(77617,33096))
```

And obtain a value that is: 1*10^32.

Why is this not to 5 sig fig? Why is this not close to a value of 7.878 * 10^29 as you increase the number of sig fig required?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reduce the working precision that low, especially if you are trying to compute an accurate answer (and then round it for convenience).

More importantly, for compound expressions the floating-point working precision (`Digits`, or the index of an `evalf` call) is just that: a specification of working precision and *not* an accuracy request.

By lowering the working precision so much you are seeing greater roundoff error in the floating-point computation.

```
restart;
f := (x, y) -> 333.75*y^6
    + x^2*(11*x^2*y^2 - y^6 - 12*y^4 - 2)
    + 5.5*y^8 + 1/2*x/y:

for d from 5 to 15 do
    evalf[5](evalf[d](f(77617,33096)));
end do;

                   32
               1 10  

                   31
              -3 10  

                   30
               1 10  

                   29
               8 10  

                    29
              7.9 10  

                    29
             7.88 10  

                     29
             7.878 10  

                     29
            7.8784 10  

                     29
            7.8785 10  

                     29
            7.8785 10  

                     29
            7.8785 10
```